# Nginx www. -> root SSL redirects

Tags: nginx, ssl

**I AM USING DINORSAUR.COM AS AN EXAMPLE, I DONT ACTUALLY OWN IT**

Trying to figure out how to get https:// www.dinosaur.com to redirect to https:// dinosaur.com  I have the certificate for www.dinosaur.com and a wildcard certificate for *.dinosaur.com.  Any ideas?  I get "This webpage is not available" when I try to go directly to https:// www.dinosaur.com but http:// www.dinosaur.com works fine  Heres my config

```
server{
        listen          80 default_server;
        server_name     ~^(?<sub>\w+\.)?(?<domain>dinosaur\.com)$;
        rewrite         ^ https://$sub$domain$request_uri;
}
server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.dinosaur.com;
        return 301 https://dinosaur.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www.dinosaur.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www.dinosaur.com.key;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
        client_max_body_size 0;
}
server{
        # THIS IS WHERE I WANT ALL TRAFFIC TO GO
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name dinosaur.com  *.dinosaur.com;
        access_log /root/logs/access.log;
        error_log /root/logs/error.log;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/chained.dinosaur.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/dinosaur.com.key;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
        client_max_body_size 0;
}
```

Comment: There's even more wrong with your setup, because it redirects to http://disney.go.com/disneyvideos/television/dinosaurs/flash.html?hbxRef=dinosaur . Try posting your actual complete configuration.

Comment: dinosaur.com is an example, sorry forgot to mention, I dont actually own that domain.  I wish I did though hahha.

Comment: Use `example.com` to be more clear